# Position text over an image in css

Tags: css, image, text

Is there another way of placing text over an image beside using `position: absolute;` ?
Working with `position: absolute;` on different screen sizes doesn't seem like the thing i want to do.
I kept looking for an answer but all i can find about it is the classic : use position absolute.

```
HTML: 


<div class="header-container">
   <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2018/04/Facebook-Cover-Photo-Size.png" alt="" id="header-img" />
        <p class="img-text">Make it possible!</p>
</div> 


CSS:


#header-container {
  max-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text-header {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Gayathri", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 1000;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a small code sample of the exact issue you are facing, or nobody will be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead,

add this style to img

```
#header-img{width:100%;height:auto;}
```

if you align text in center by

```
.text-header{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```css
#header-container {
  max-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#header-img{width:100%;height:auto;}
.text-header {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Gayathri", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 1000;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-weight:800;
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
   <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2018/04/Facebook-Cover-Photo-Size.png" alt="" id="header-img" />
        <p class="text-header">Make it possible!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That`s what i was looking for. The first version before edit was nice too, can be a good design. Where can i learn more about -webkit-transform and transform property?

Comment: Read [this to more information about the overlay effect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp)

Comment: This is helpsful you too [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, no.

However, you can combine a text element with `position: absolute` inside of an element with `position: relative`. This will position the element in an absolute manner (based on pixels/percentages *relative to* the parent element itself, rather than the entire document.

Expanding on this, you could include an image in said element (either as a background image or as another absolutely positioned div, and use percentages to position your text relative to the container.

```css
#rel{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
h1{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="rel">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to check the first answer in this page.